# Magento CE 2.2.2: How to add images to my custom payment plugin module?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.2, payment, knockoutjs, plugin

I am creating a custom payment plugin for **Magento 2.2.2** For the plugin I need to add the payment icons and some other images.

How can I add images for my custom payment plugin?

I tried all the steps mentioned in [Magento 2 : How to Add Image to Payment Method in Checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243920/magento-2-how-to-add-image-to-payment-method-in-checkout) but after following these steps I'm getting the following error

> Failed to load the "_/js/view/payment/method-renderer/" component.

Anyone has a solution for this? Any help  will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from [How to specify skin image path in Knockout HTML template?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172722/how-to-specify-skin-image-path-in-knockout-html-template/172726)

require.toUrl('')+'/images/icon.png';

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. In your HTML template file add this image element

```
 <img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('images/payment/akg.png') }" />
```

Now add an image into your module's or theme web folder like this,

> view/frontend/web/js/images/payment/akg.png

now if you want to add the payment method icons.

follow this.

```
<div data-bind="attr: {class: 'payment-method'}, css: {'_active': isActive()}">
<div class="payment-method-title field choice">
    <input type="radio"
           name="payment[method]"
           class="radio"
           data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('CyberSource_SecureAcceptance/images/hbl/hbl.png'), alt: $t('Pay via EJAZ-ALAM')}"
         class="payment-icon"/> <!-- here I added that image tag with image directory path, It will add image on frontend with payment method. -->
    <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}">
        <span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="payment-method-content">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="" id="cybersource-post-form"></form>

    <form id="chcybersource_form" class="form" data-bind="" method="post" action="#">
        <!-- ko if: (isSilentPost())-->
            <!-- ko template: 'CyberSource_SecureAcceptance/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: (isVaultEnabled())-->
            <div class="field choice">
                <input type="checkbox"
                       name="vault[is_enabled]"
                       class="checkbox"
                       data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}, checked: vaultEnabler.isActivePaymentTokenEnabler"/>
                <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode() + '_enable_vault'}">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Save for later use.'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <input type="submit" id="chcybersource_submit"  style="display:none" />
    </form>
    <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button class="action primary checkout"
                    type="submit"
                    data-bind="
                    click: placeOrderToCyberSource,
                    css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                    attr: {title: $t('Place Order')}
            ">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```