# How can add credit card, visa etc icon checkout magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Add Payment Method Logo (credit card, Bank Transfer Payment etc) In checkout/#payment as like paypal icon in magento 2

[image]

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243977

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following way. This is only for the Banktransfer payment method. You need to change the same way for others:

***Step 1:*** *How you pass data to the checkout*

**app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="add_logo_in_bank_transfer_payment_config_provider" xsi:type="object">SR\MagentoCommunity\Model\BanktransferConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now create config provider class:

**app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Model/BanktransferConfigProvider.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;

class BanktransferConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Repository
     */
    private $assetRepository;

    /**
     * BanktransferConfigProvider constructor.
     *
     * @param Repository $assetRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Repository $assetRepository
    ) {
        $this->assetRepository = $assetRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $banktransferLogoUrl = $this->assetRepository->getUrlWithParams('SR_MagentoCommunity::images/banktransfer_logo.png', []);
        return [
            'payment' => [
                'banktransfer' => [
                    'banktransferLogoUrl' => $banktransferLogoUrl
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** *Now you need to overwrite js class of payment method.*

**app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/banktransfer-method': {
                'SR_MagentoCommunity/js/mixin/banktransfer-method-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/banktransfer-method-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko'
], function ($, ko) {
    'use strict';

    return function (banktransferMethod) {
        return banktransferMethod.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'SR_MagentoCommunity/payment/banktransfer'
            },
            getLogoUrl: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.banktransfer.banktransferLogoUrl;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/frontend/web/template/payment/banktransfer.html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <img data-bind="attr: {src: getLogoUrl(), height: '39', width: '163'}" class="payment-icon" />
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <p data-bind="html: getInstructions()"></p>
        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {'title': $t('Place Order')},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked()),
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()}
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Clear cache. If Magento mode is not developer, redeploy static content***